# Make Kestrel use Ubuntu's self-signed certs

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, ssl, kestrel-http-server, pfx

Ubuntu already has self-signed certs, `/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem` and `/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key`

Is it possible to use those with a netcore app on Kestrel instead of generating a PFX?

If so, what's the required config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kestrel added support for pem files so you can specify them in configuration specifed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#replace-the-default-certificate-from-configuration-1

```
{
"HttpsInlineCertAndKeyFile": {
    "Url": "https://localhost:5002",
    "Certificate": {
        "Path": "<path to .pem/.crt file>",
        "KeyPath": "<path to .key file>",
        "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$"
    }
}
}
```